# Flow in Datasource or Repository?

Tags: android, repository, datasource, kotlin-flow

Where should I emit data with the flow? Repository or Datasource? Why?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific use case and design, you can use Flow in both a repository and a data source in Android.

In a repository, you might use Flow to expose a stream of data to the rest of your app. For example, you might have a repository that retrieves a list of users from a database or API.
In a data source, you might use Flow to asynchronously stream data from a data source to the repository or the UI layer. For example, you might have a data source that retrieves a large dataset from a remote API.

***Which one is common?***

Using Flow in a repository is more common in Android development. This is because a repository is often used as an abstraction layer between the data sources and the rest of the app, and it provides a clean API for accessing and modifying data.

Using Flow in a repository can make it easy to observe changes to the data and handle asynchronous operations, such as network requests or database queries, in a clean and efficient way